# How to import remote library in Android Studio using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import android-swipelistview (https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) into my Android Studio module using gradle. Shouldn't this be possible with build.gradle config alone? Does anyone have a config file(s) that does the job?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use:

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

or if you have the library copied to your project libs directory, you can use:

```
compile files ('libs/ nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
```

However, you can check out my post on getting started with swipelistview:
http://modewagon.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/getting-started-with-swipelistview/

Comment: compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+' is not working.

Error:(21, 13) Failed to resolve: com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+

Comment: just remove the "+" at the end

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a Failed to Resolve error on this library. The fix for me was, in the *build.gradle* file, to change this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to this:

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If  compile **'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+'** doesn't work,

try this -> **compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'**

Comment: I'm getting the Failed to Resolve error with the library as well. I've tried "...2.4.0" and "...2.4.+", but these have no effect.