# Material design library requiring oldnineandroids 2.4.+: build failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I am trying to build my Android app that compiled just fine until a few days ago. Now, I had to move my project, I made some changes and I need to rebuild it, but I get the following error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/nineoldandroids/library/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/nineoldandroids/library/
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/nineoldandroids/library/maven-metadata.xml
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/nineoldandroids/library/
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/nineoldandroids/library/maven-metadata.xml
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/nineoldandroids/library/
         file:~/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/nineoldandroids/library/maven-metadata.xml
         file:~/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/nineoldandroids/library/
         file:~/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/nineoldandroids/library/maven-metadata.xml
         file:~/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/nineoldandroids/library/
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.2
```

There is no folder `nineoldandroids` in `~/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/` nor `~/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/`

How do I fix this?

===EDIT===
My app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.lh.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.2.1@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)** is deprecated. No new development will be taking place. Existing versions will (of course) continue to function. New applications should use **`minSdkVersion="14" or higher which has access`** to the platform animation APIs.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find any version that matches com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+.

You can use  `compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'`

```
dependencies 
   {
   compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
   }
```

**Edit**

move `compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')` before compile `'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.2'`.

Comment: @Manu Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572430/how-to-import-remote-library-in-android-studio-using-gradle

Comment: @Manu Go though above URL . i used  `compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')`

Comment: I read that question, but still it doesn't work: I get the same error in all mentioned cases.

Comment: @Manu CAN YOU SHARE YOUR `BUILD.GRADLE` ?

Comment: you can use `targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: @Manu did you click "add as library" whenever you set ?

Comment: Tried targetSdkVersion 23, but I still get the error. No, I was not prompted to add is as a library.

Comment: Right click on the .JAR file and select the last option Add as library.

Comment: have  a look here http://inducesmile.com/android/android-studio-add-jar-file-as-android-library/

Comment: Then `clean -rebuild-restart -sync` project .Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, we did it! I had to do everything you recommended, but I also had to move compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar') before compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.2'. Thanks!

Comment: @Manu Move ahead . Happy coding .

Comment: And also "transitive = false" to the requiring library!

Comment: @Manu indeed indeed .

Answer (score 1):

This library is not distributed by Google, but by Jack Wharton. You can download it from GitHub or get a link from Maven.

I don't know what happend in your project, but you can just clear it and add it once again. To get it from Maven follow these steps:

Open module settings in Android Studio, go to Dependencies tab, find nineoldandroid and remove it. Then add a Library dependency using that little '+' on the right. Type 'nineoldandroids', search, pick the one you want and click OK.

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately, still the same issue.

Comment: Seems like it's a common issue for that library. Did you try to follow these steps: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/370 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to exchnage 0 and + in the library version, but nothing good happens.

Answer (score 0):

From [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

> Including In Your Project
>
> This library is presented as a .jar file which you can include in the
>   libs/ folder of your application. You can download the latest version
>   from the GitHub downloads page.